# Putting space between options of a horizontal navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I've created a basic horizontal navigation bar. It has your generic options: Homepage, contact us, about, and games. However, even though contact us, games, and Homepage are close together, I want to make it so about is on the opposite side of the web page/navigation bar, far away from the others but still connected to it through a huge empty space of the navigation bar. How would I go about doing this? Below is my current CSS code if it helps:

```
.horiznavli {
    display: inline;
    padding:20px 32px 20px;
    border-color: #333333;
    background-color: #333;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Times, Serif

}

.horiznavli:hover{

background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.horiznavli:active{
    background-color: grey;
}

#HorizNav{

    position: relative;
    left: -60px

}

#HorizNav #spaced {


}
```

EDIT: My apologies here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="frontpage.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Official Dark Matter Studios site">
        <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Studio, Game, Dark Matter">
        <meta name="author" Content="Matt Jones">

        <title> Dark Matter Studios </title>

    </head>

<body>
<ol id = "HorizNav" style = "list-style-type:none">
<li class = "horiznavli"> HomePage </li>
<li class = "horiznavli"> About </li>
<li class = "horiznavli"> Games </li>
<li class = "horiznavli" id = "spaced"> Conact Us </li>
</ol>




<h1 id="title_screen"> Dark Matter Studios</h1>
    <div id="wrapper">

    <h1> What is Dark Matter Studios all about? </h1>

        <p> Dark Matter studios is an independent game development dedicated to producing quality games out of a passion and love for gaming.<br>
        Born from the frustration of anti-consumerism, microtransactions and DLC eccentric practices held by many AAA companies </p>    

<br>
<br>
    <h1> WHAT WE'RE ALL ABOUT </h1> 

    <p> Dark Matter Studios was founded around the principle of honesty and integrity with our fans. After all, without them we wouldn't get anywhere! Though Dark Matter studios holds itself responible the following standards: </p>

    <ol style="list-style-type: circle">
    <li> Honesty with our customers. </li>
    <li> No Microtransactions or overpriced DLC</li>
    <li> We are honest with our customers, we don't promise things and not deliver</li>
    <li> We promise high quality games, with no graphical downgrades on release</li>
    <li> We stick to our word, we do not mislead our customers to gain a quick buck off them</li>
    </ol>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: post HTML code also.. or try to fiddle here

Comment: Give 'about' in separate ul and make it float right

Answer (score 0):

```
.horiznavli {
   float:left;
    padding:20px 32px 20px;
    border-color: #333333;
    background-color: #333;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Times, Serif

}

.horiznavli:hover{

background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.horiznavli:active{
    background-color: grey;
}

#HorizNav{

    position: relative;
    left: -60px

}

#HorizNav #spaced {


}

#HorizNav.ul li:nth-child(3)
{
    float:right!important;
    margin-left:100px!important;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Instead, explain what your code does and how/why it may solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you had added your html code as well. Anyway if you are using bootstrap you can use this code and no need of css.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Homepage <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Otherwise if you are using html and css only, use this code.

```
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
 </head>
<body>

<ul>
   <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#news">Games</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   <li style="float:right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Tell me if this is what you wanted.